# OK to update hugo?

Tags: r-markdown, hugo, blogdown

I am running a 2 year old version of the Hugo academic theme with `blogdown`.  The latest version of `hugo` on Ubuntu 19.10 repos is 0.58.  The newest version is 0.65 if downloaded from the Hugo website.  Is updating a good idea for my use on `.Rmd` and `.Rmarkdown` files?  Newer versions of Hugo have richer markdown such as the ability to handling [floating table of contents](https://gohugo.io/content-management/toc).

Comment: It depends on what you need. For example, I'm still using Hugo 0.25.1 for my personal website, because I haven't seen any new features in later versions of Hugo that I'd need. Upgrading Hugo is easy (so is downgrading), but it can be complicated when considering the support for different versions of Hugo in Hugo themes. I'd say you can try updating first (if it breaks, you are still free to downgrade). The hugo-academic theme is a fairly complicated theme in my eyes, so I wouldn't be surprised if the older version of academic doesn't work with a newer version of Hugo.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case someone stumbles onto this question, I would like to describe what I have found. Updating Hugo ***has*** broken a site for me! This was from version 0.58 to v0.72
The solution was quite lengthy involving trying versions via binary sort (simple process of using a "middle" version, ie v0.65 and if it works, split the upper half. If it does not work, split the lower half. Then repeat ). The versions of Hugo are available on Github https://github.com/gohugoio/hugo/releases (hope this url is allowed! If not you can Google for it)

The theme, however updated without problems (meghna-hugo).

Hugo Academic theme has been "taken over" by Wowchemy and has got tied up in their ecosystem. Check wowchemy [dot] com

Some themes have a specified minimum Hugo version. If the min version is hard coded into the config.toml file, just lowering the min version could get it working like it did for me. YMMV

Comment: I found it easier to start a new project and copy over all posts from the old project, then to redirect the old url to the new project.  wowchemy is cool.